# Sentence pattern for describing a list of objects

Tags: syntax

I was trying to describe a list of objects from a more generic point of view to a more specific one. While at the generic level I feel quite sure, using for example.

> みなりのポケットの中には、ボールペンを二本あります。
>   There are two pens in the dress' pocket.

When trying to be more specific describing those pens I feel like I'm missing something (probably grammar). I would say something like:

> 一本は赤いです、一方は青いです。
>   One is red and the other is blue.

Is that correct/natural? Are there other (better) ways to express the same concept?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> みなりのポケットの中には、ボールペンを二本あります。
>   There are two pens in the dress' pocket.

[身]{み}なり refers to how you are dressed, your appearance, etc. Use ドレス for dress as in long dress or wedding dress, 服 or 洋服 for general clothes. を is used to indicate an object; use the subject particle が since the ボールペン is the subject of あります. あります would be fine but 入っています would be more natural. I would go with:

> ドレス/[服]{ふく}のポケットには、ボールペンが二本[入]{はい}っています。

---

> 一本は赤いです、一方は青いです。
>   One is red and the other is blue.

Your translation makes sense but to be grammatically correct, you would say

> 一本は赤で、もう一本は青です。
>   or 一本は赤色で、もう一本は青色です。

「赤で」「青です」「赤色で」「青色です」 are like saying "(pens) of red/blue colour", rather than describing how the pens look.

Comment: Thank you! Just for clarity, with 入っています do you describe the fact that the pocket contains the pens? So should I use it every time I want to describe the content of something?

Comment: I am not sure it's "every time" but yes you basically use 入っています to say "something is in a pocket, box, bag, etc." "someone is in a club", "some ingredient is in food, drink" etc.